# Custom Number Format not Showing in Arrayformula (Maybe Due to Script?)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

**EDIT:** Added example sheet for clarity. Sorry for the delay, the real sheet is complicated and I had to track down which bits were most relevant to use in said example, while also being confident that I've recreated the error. [Here it is](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Vf09wFFg9JHtyJFvGnkfALkDmrw9b-qwZPoLnxLC0dw/edit?usp=sharing)!

I have a script that's meant to change the number format of data when a dropdown is edited. It works for the most part, but when copying an array, the number format doesn't show at all.

I've tried a conditional if statement making sure numbers are read as numbers. I've tried setting all the places the array works to automatic number format. I checked to see if it's just an issue reading custom formats, but if I type in, say, $3, $8, $14, that particular data transcribes just fine. I'm not sure how I could make the array have the script applied to certain positions in the array, considering its contents change based on different options (sometimes not showing anything needing the number formatting at all.)

I will be happy to share and explain the spreadsheet itself if need be, but it is incredibly dense. It's complicated enough that I'm not sure I could make an example sheet easily.

The apps script is this (It's a mess, I know, I'm currently working on condensing it this morning):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var displaySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Display");
  var tempStyle = displaySheet.getRange("G2").getValues();
  var gasT = sheet.getRange("GasTemps");
  var liquidT1 = sheet.getRange("LiquidTemps1");
  var liquidT2 = sheet.getRange("LiquidTemps2");
  var liquidT3 = sheet.getRange("LiquidTemps3");
  var stoneT1 = sheet.getRange("StoneTemps1");
  var stoneT2 = sheet.getRange("StoneTemps2");
  var metalT1 = sheet.getRange("MetalTemps1");
  var metalT2 = sheet.getRange("MetalTemps2");
  var otherT1 = sheet.getRange("OtherTemps1");
  var otherT2 = sheet.getRange("OtherTemps2");
  displaySheet.getRange("G2");
  
  // Always show 3 decimal points 
      if (tempStyle =="Kelvin") 
      {gasT.setNumberFormat('#,##0.0##" K"');
      liquidT1.setNumberFormat('#,##0.0##" K"');
      liquidT2.setNumberFormat('#,##0.0##" K"');
      liquidT3.setNumberFormat('#,##0.0##" K"');
      stoneT1.setNumberFormat('#,##0.0##" K"');
      stoneT2.setNumberFormat('#,##0.0##" K"');
      metalT1.setNumberFormat('#,##0.0##" K"');
      metalT2.setNumberFormat('#,##0.0##" K"');
      otherT1.setNumberFormat('#,##0.0##" K"');
      otherT2.setNumberFormat('#,##0.0##" K"')}
        if (tempStyle =="Mixed")
          {gasT.setNumberFormat('#,##0.0##"°C"');
          liquidT1.setNumberFormat('#,##0.0##"°C"');
          liquidT2.setNumberFormat('#,##0.0##"°C"');
          liquidT3.setNumberFormat('#,##0.0##"°C"');
          stoneT1.setNumberFormat('#,##0.0##" K"');
          stoneT2.setNumberFormat('#,##0.0##" K"');
          metalT1.setNumberFormat('#,##0.0##" K"');
          metalT2.setNumberFormat('#,##0.0##" K"');
          otherT1.setNumberFormat('#,##0.0##" K"');
          otherT2.setNumberFormat('#,##0.0##" K"')}
            if (tempStyle == "Celsius")
            {gasT.setNumberFormat('#,##0.0##"°C"');
            liquidT1.setNumberFormat('#,##0.0##"°C"');
            liquidT2.setNumberFormat('#,##0.0##"°C"');
            liquidT3.setNumberFormat('#,##0.0##"°C"');
            stoneT1.setNumberFormat('#,##0.0##"°C"');
            stoneT2.setNumberFormat('#,##0.0##"°C"');
            metalT1.setNumberFormat('#,##0.0##"°C"');
            metalT2.setNumberFormat('#,##0.0##"°C"');
            otherT1.setNumberFormat('#,##0.0##"°C"');
            otherT2.setNumberFormat('#,##0.0##"°C"')}
              if (tempStyle =="Fahrenheit") 
                {gasT.setNumberFormat('#,##0.000"°F"');
                liquidT1.setNumberFormat('#,##0.0##"°F"');
                liquidT2.setNumberFormat('#,##0.0##"°F"');
                liquidT3.setNumberFormat('#,##0.0##"°F"');
                stoneT1.setNumberFormat('#,##0.0##"°F"');
                stoneT2.setNumberFormat('#,##0.0##"°F"');
                metalT1.setNumberFormat('#,##0.0##"°F"');
                metalT2.setNumberFormat('#,##0.0##"°F"');
                otherT1.setNumberFormat('#,##0.0##"°F"');
                otherT2.setNumberFormat('#,##0.0##"°F"')}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I'm having issues communicating the error. Will these images help? If not, I might just need to post the sheet itself.

1. The relevant formula, the list in question--under the right left cell
2. The display page; the circled values are all temperature values. The last section (All) doesn't show units.
3. On the left, 4 lists populated by results of other lookups. On the right, a list of properties that the two elements compared (in "All" section in image 2) have in common.
4. An example of a page of information the vlookups are drawing from.

[image: The relevant formula, the list in question--under the right left cell]
[image: The display page; the circled values are all temperature values. The last section (All) doesn't show units.]
[image: On the left, 4 lists populated by results of other lookups. On the right, a list of properties that the two elements compared (in "All" section in image 2) have in common.]
[image: An example of a page of information the vlookups are drawing from.]

Comment: Paste values only?

Comment: The values of the array? Not possible. The array changes based on a variety of options, then a calculation is executed on that dynamic array.

Comment: This: `It works for the most part, but when copying an array, the number format doesn't show at all` is not clear. Do you mean copying a range array(say A2:C15) and pasting it manually?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `I'm not sure how I could make the array have the script applied to certain positions in the array`. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: 1. The range is being copied by listing an arrayformula. 2. Edited. Will the images above help?

Comment: Thank you for replying. And, I noticed your reply just now. I apologize for this. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your current issue. I cannot understand the relationship between your added 4 images and your showing script and your issue. In order to correctly understand your current issue, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet for correctly replicating your current issue? When you reply by including `@username`, the user can notice your reply.

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you for teaching me how to tag! And, if you're still interested in helping me, I finally made an example sheet. [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Vf09wFFg9JHtyJFvGnkfALkDmrw9b-qwZPoLnxLC0dw/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let me propose this solution.  Instead of multiple `getRange()` with the name of each named range, construct a [RangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRangeList(String)). A `RangeList` will not accept the name of a named range but it will accept the A1 notation of a range.

I loop through all the named ranges in the sheet and get the A1 notation of requested names.  I deliberately built 2 list for the Mixed category and if its not mixed simply merge together.

```
function test() {
  try {
    let names = ["GasTemps","LiquidTemps1","LiquidTemps2","LiquidTemps3",
                  "StoneTemps1","StoneTemps2","MetalTemps1","MetalTemps2",
                  "OtherTemps1","OtherTemps2"];
    let formats = ['#,##0.0##" K"','#,##0.0##"°C"','#,##0.000"°F"'];
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    let namedRanges = sheet.getNamedRanges();
    // build 2 lists for Mixed category
    let rangeList = [[],[]];
    let tempStyle = "Mixed";
    namedRanges.forEach( range => {
        let index = names.indexOf(range.getName());
        if( index >= 0 ) {
          // index < 4 gas/liquid > 4 others
          index = index < 4 ? 0 : 1;
          // get the A1 notation of each named range
          rangeList[index].push(range.getRange().getA1Notation());
        }
      }
    );
    let ranges = null;
    if( tempStyle === "Mixed" ) {
      ranges = sheet.getRangeList(rangeList[0]);
      ranges.setNumberFormat(formats[1]);
      ranges = sheet.getRangeList(rangeList[1]);
      ranges.setNumberFormat(formats[0]);
    }
    else {
      // flatten into one array
      rangeList = rangeList.flat();
      ranges = sheet.getRangeList(rangeList);
      ranges.setNumberFormat(formats[0]);
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

**References**

- [Sheet.getNamedRanges()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getNamedRanges())
- [Range.getA1Notation()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getA1Notation())
- [Sheet.getRangeList()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRangeList(String))
- [RangeList.setNumberFormat()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list#setNumberFormat(String))
- [Array.forEach()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp)
- [Array.indexOf()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp)
- [Array.flat()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_array_flat.asp)

Comment: I'm not sure I get getNamedRanges--it's telling me that the named ranges are null, and I'm not sure how to fix that problem. I tried looking at the reference (you linked) itself, but there doesn't seem to be a difference in what the code is doing...not to me, anyway. I'm very new at this particular aspect of Sheets, excuse me for that.

Comment: You must have a named range called "GasTemps" in the sheet?  If it is returning `null` then it may be the wrong sheet?  Remember this is my test and sheet name may not match your spreadsheet.

Comment: Sorry for the long wait! I decided to come back to the project to try and get through the issues, since I have too many questions to ask about using this code. I wanted to at least get a little better before I asked any questions (this is all incredibly new.) The first thing I have to ask: Is getSheetByName only pulling from the page I decide (front page "Display")? These ranges are spread out over different pages, which is why I use "getSheetByName" so much. Would you please tell me how I should get multiple ranges from multiple sheets? There's an example sheet.

Comment: You only use 1 sheet for the named ranges `var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];`  and I don't see `displaySheet` used at all.  But of course you could loop through as many sheets as you want.